# Como compilar no Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

Instalei o MingW e nas instuções há a indicação de: *Make sure your compiler executable is in your platform path so the extension can find it*. Como se faz?

Obrigada, isto é tudo novo para mim.

Answer (score 1):

O aviso está pedindo para que coloque o caminho do compilador que está usando no PATH do seu sistema operacional.

Se estiver usando Windows, este local seria as "variáveis de ambiente":

Em Pesquisar, procure e selecione: Sistema (Painel de Controle)

1. Clique no link Configurações avançadas do sistema.
2. Clique em **Variáveis de Ambiente**. Na seção Variáveis do Sistema, localize a variável de ambiente PATH e selecione-a. Clique em Editar.
3. Clique em Novo. Na janela de Nova Variável de Sistema, adicione uma nova com o caminho até o binário do compilador. Se, por exemplo, instalou o [mingw-w64](https://www.eclipse.org/4diac/documentation/html/installation/minGW.html) em C:/mingw-w64/, o caminho será `C:/mingw-w64/bin`

O caminho vai depender do compilador que você escolheu. No Windows, a documentação do Visual Studio Code recomenda o mingw-w64 para trabalhar com C/C++ e [no link](https://www.eclipse.org/4diac/documentation/html/installation/minGW.html) tem instruções (em inglês) mais detalhadas sobre este processo com este compilador.